# Python: manipulating bits in a char in a string

Tags: python, bit

I know how to read bits inside an int in Python but not how to do so on a char.
For an int, this elementary operation works: a & (2**bit_index) . But for a single character it gives the following error message: `unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'`

In case, this "subtlety' matters, I'm also reading my char from a string object using:

```
for my_char in my_string:
```

I'm stressing this point, because it could be that my_char is actually a string of length one and not a char, just because I know really little about python handle of types.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the `ord()` function, but beware of Unicode chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead: `ord(a) & (2**bit_index)`.

In python there is no separate character type, a character is simply a string of size one. So if you want to perform bit manipulations with string of size 1, you can use [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#ord) to convert it to `int`.

Comment: Thank you, I chose this solution among the others because it's the simplest to implement in what I had already done ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `bytearray` instead of a string.  The individual elements are integers, but you can still do basic string manipulation on the whole:

```
>>> arr = bytearray('foo')
>>> type(arr[0])
<type 'int'>
>>> arr.replace('o', 'u')
bytearray(b'fuu')
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct -- it is a string of length 1 and not a char.

Convert your string to a list of integers:

```
>>> s = "hello world"
>>> l = [ord(c) for c in s]
```

Then you can use bitwise operators on specific offsets:

```
>>> l[1] = l[1] << 1
>>> print "".join(chr(c) for c in l)
h?llo world
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't really have char type. You have a string of length one. You need to convert it to int before you can apply those operators in it. Depending on what is in `my_string` this might work: `int(my_char, 10)`